# Что такое суррогатный, естественный и бизнес ключ?

Tags: база-данных

Не нашёл информации по этому поводу, тем более русскоязычной.

Что такое бизнес-ключ, если рассматривать его в контексте СУРБД? Я правильно понимаю, что бизнес-ключ, это какая-то реальная информация о сущности, с помощью которой её можно идентифицировать? То есть, например, e-mail или номер телефона будет бизнес-ключом для человека? И обязательно ли бизнес-ключ должен быть уникальным?

Чем также являются суррогатные и естественные ключи, и к чему из них относится бизнес-ключ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бизнес-ключ, он же естественный ключ - это индекс, который определяет уникальность строки на основе комбинации значений столбцов, которые естественным образом существуют в таблице в соответствии с бизнес-правилами.

Суррогатный, он же синтетический, ключ - это индекс, который определяет уникальность строки на основе столбца, значение которого предоставляется самостоятельным, независимым, никак не связанным с бизнес-правилами, генератором, гарантирующим уникальность предоставляемого значения в пределах времени жизни таблицы.

PS. В реальных условиях свойство уникальности ключа не гарантируется вследствие ограничений, налагаемых на тип данных, и соответственно ограниченного количества возможных значений ключа. Однако на практике достаточно практической недостижимости предела количества значений.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Меня заинтересовала фраза "который определяет уникальность строки на основе комбинации значений столбцов". Значит ли это то, что бизнес/естественный ключ всегда генерируется на основании нескольких полей? Он не может быть сгенерирован на основании одного поля, e-mail например?

Comment: @Zhenyria *Значит ли это то, что бизнес/естественный ключ всегда генерируется на основании нескольких полей?* С чего бы? Что мешает комбинации включать в себя только одно поле?

Comment: комбинация по определению "Сочетание, взаимное расположение чего-н.". Не может же одно поле сочетаться само с собой?

Впрочем, я не пытаюсь придраться к словам, меня действительно интересует то, как это происходит на самом деле.

Comment: @Zhenyria Вы попробуйте математику сказать, что формула для расчёта количества комбинаций не должна учитывать комбинации из одного элемента...